# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'

Tags: magento-1.7

I migrated my magento site ..it migrated successfully bt when i import database it keep on showing error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link.area' in 'where clause'"

what does that mean??? please help

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is a column missing in your `core_layout_link` table called `area`, you should check using something like PHPMyAdmin.

**EDIT (as per comment):** It seems Magento doesn't give the full name of the table prefix.

Comment: bt there is no table named as link...i checked in database

Comment: That's clearly the problem. Check your previous database before the migration, one (or more) module(s) is dependant on that table for functionality which is causing the SQLSTATE error.

Comment: i checked my previous database..and i am sure that it does not have any such table..even where clause is not used in full database..do have any solution..i will b very thankful to you

Comment: Strange. Could you do me a favor and please run a reindex on your site? From SSH you can call `/shell php indexer.php reindexall` - let me know if this resolves things for you.

Comment: This behavior is definitely triggered by a missing table and or column. To narrow down your problem I'd go the route of disabling your third party extensions one by one and refreshing the page to see if the issue persists. Once the issue stops persisting, check the `sql` folder in the module's directory to try and identify which table that module is meant to install. The installer script is obviously not running.

Comment: thanks moose u were write it was a missing column named 'area' in 'core_layout_link' table...thanks alot man..you made my day..:)

Comment: Glad you managed to come right, strange that they don't give you the full table name in the error message.